# file not found, file doesn't exist (jpg)

Tags: python, image, tkinter

File not found, no such file or directory

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os
import sys

root = Tk() # Create the root (base) window 
root.title("tkinter experiment")
root.iconbitmap("knuckes_-_Copy.ico")

canvas = Canvas(root, width=210, height=210, background="bisque")
canvas.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)

img = open("knuckles.jpg", "r")
panel = Label(root, image = img)
panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")

root.mainloop()
```

I'd expect the file "knuckles.jpg" to be stored in the img variable for later use in a window, instead, the terminal returns that the file doesn't exist even though its in the same directory as the .py file.

error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Image.py", line 14, in <module>
    img = open("knuckles.jpg", "r")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'knuckles.jpg'
```

Comment: Please also include your error log

Comment: You probably want `img = PhotoImage(file="knuckles.jpg")` anyway. (Though that's probably not the issue with finding the file.)

Comment: Probably `img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("knuckles.jpg"))` since he is opening a `jpg`. But still it doesnt solve his path issue.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the full path instead of just the file name will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems in this code. you are not using Image and ImageTk or you referred a wrong example.

```
img = open("knuckles.jpg", "r")
```

Correct code line should be

```
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("knuckles.jpg","r"))
```

You can try to change and execute. I just tried and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if it's in the same file as the .py file -- that's not where python looks for files. It looks for files in your current working directory, which may be different than the location of the script.

If you want to look in the same folder as the script, you need to compute that with something like this:

```
import os.path
...
script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
image_file = os.path.join(script_dir, "knuckles.jpg")
```

You have other problems in your code, such as tkinter not supporting .jpg files and the `img` parameter not taking an open file handle, but the above answers the "file not found" issue which is what you were asking about.